# Nginx config works with IP but not with domain name

Tags: apache, nginx, dns

I wanted to point a website on an IP address, however the Nginx configuration is ignored when using the hostname URL, and I just land on the default page.

Maybe there is something I don't understand, but isn't a hostname just a more human-readable address? Then why would it work on the IP but not on the hostname?

My IP address is: 195.110.58.43

My URL is : `http://www.bzteam.fr/`

And here is the config

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name bzteam.fr, www.bzteam.fr, 195.110.58.43;
  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location /static/ {
    root /home/wipoulou/bzteam;
  }

  location / {
    include         uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass      unix:/run/uwsgi/bzteam.sock;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if I set something wrong, or if there is something I don't understand about hostnames.

Just a detail, the website was made using Django, and the hostname was added in the allowed_hosts.

Comment: Do you have both `apache` and `nginx` running?

Comment: I think so, I set it up using digital ocean tutorial.

Comment: What article so we can get a sense of what you set up

Comment: Your DNS resolution is fine, both `www.bzteam.fr` and `bzteam.fr` resolve to `195.110.58.43`. So now you just need to make sure that the HTTP server/proxy running on this IP is configured for these two names.

Comment: I have tried to edit your post a little but when you say "on the DNS" this is really not clear what you are talking about. The DNS is a system to map, for the web world in particular, hostnames to IP addresses. hostnames are used in the URLs, after the scheme part (`http:` or `https:`). It seams in your sentences sometimes DNS means hostname sometimes it means the webserver, etc. Please try to fix that so that it is easier to understand. Also it is not strictly programming related, so you may be more on topic on [sf] or [webmaster.se], make sure to read their tour and help pages.

Comment: The article is https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04.

Comment: I mean hostname all along I think. I'm going to try and see what is my http server configuration.

Comment: I read the tutorial again and I only see the hostname setup twice, once in django, once in the configuration file I copy/pasted... I'm not sure where else I should add the hostname as allowed

Comment: There are no commas in the `server_name` directive. The names should be space separated. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).

Comment: Yes thank you, I just changed it. Hope that does it because I'm not sure as to what else I'm supposed to set up.

Comment: It did! Ayy, thank you guys

Comment: Also the server ip address should not be included in the `server_name` directive, it's an optional parameter for the `listen` directive, eg `listen 195.110.58.43:80;`

Comment: Good to know, though I removed it altogether because it didn't really make sense to let users access the website from the IP address.